# Advanced Geometry

Tags: geometry

From the vertex A of a triangle ABC draw perpendiculars AM and AP to the bisectors of the exterior angles of ABC at the vertices B and C.  Find the length of PM if the perimeter of ABC is 10.

Been working on this for a very long time.  I tried angle chasing to get triangle similarities.  I also tried to relate the ratio of areas to find the ratio of the triangles but could not find one that stuck.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Hint: if indeed $PM$ depends on the perimeter, only, then it would be the same if you "flatten" a triangle until $A$ lands on $BC\,$, in which case the base angles tend to $0$, the external bisectors tend to perpendiculars on $BC$, and therefore $PM$ tends to $5$. So at least you know the answer you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external bisectors of B and C will meet at X, the ex-center. Then, $AX$ is the internal angle bisector of $\angle A$. Therefore, $\angle BAX = a$.[image]

It should be clear that MA is parallel to BV, the internal angle bisector of B. Then, $\angle MAB = b$. Similarly, $\angle BCX = 90^{\circ}- c$.

Let MP cut AB at H, AX at S, BV at T and AC at K.

AMXP is cyclic implies $\alpha = \beta$.

$\angle 1 = \alpha + b + a$ and $\angle 2 = \beta + (90^{\circ} – c)$. Therefore, $\angle 1 = \angle 2$ because $2a + 2b + 2c = 180^{\circ}$. This further means MP // BC. Then, $\alpha = \delta = b$. That means HM = HA.

It is not difficult to see that HM = HB also. Similarly, KA = KP = KC.

By midpoint theorem, HK = $\frac1{2}$BC.

The required result can be found from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Let our bisectors intersect in the point $Q$.

Hence, $Q$ is a center of the circle,

which tangents to the line $AB$ in the point $L$ and tangents to the line $AC$ in the point $K$.

Since $$\measuredangle AMQ=\measuredangle ALQ=\measuredangle APQ=\measuredangle AKQ=90^{\circ},$$
we see that $AMLQKP$ is cyclic and $AQ$ is a diameter of him circle.

Let $O$ is a center of the circle (a middle point of $AQ$).

Thus, $$\measuredangle MOA=180^{\circ}-2\measuredangle MAO=180^{\circ}-2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}\right)=\gamma$$ and 
$$\measuredangle POA=180^{\circ}-2\measuredangle PAO=180^{\circ}-2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)=\beta.$$
Thus, $\measuredangle MOP=\gamma+\beta=180-\alpha$.

But since $\measuredangle OAK=\frac{\alpha}{2}$, we obtain
$$\measuredangle AOK=180^{\circ}-2\cdot\frac{\alpha}{2}=180^{\circ}-\alpha.$$
Id est, $\measuredangle MOP=\measuredangle AOK$, which gives
$$MP=AK=\frac{10}{2}=5.$$
Done!